# Show poster after video is finished

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I use a video as the background of a page, the video plays when the page launches.  When the video is done, I want to use an image as the background of my page, the image is actually the last frame of the video, which is a higher quality version of the last frame of the video.

My approach is to use the poster attribute of the video tag.
I would set the poster after video is played, but poster would not show when the video stop as it stay on the last frame of the video file, so I use javascript to monitor the end of the video play and:

Setting src to null will show the poster of the video tag

`document.getElementById("video-player").setAttribute("src", null);`

but removing the source from video will not show the poster but the last frame of the previously removed video.

`document.getElementById("video-player").removeAttribute("src");`

My question is whether there is a better way to show the poster of the video tag because setting src to null not only seems like a hack but it also gives me 404 error, although it works.

**EDIT**:
This will reload my poster after removal of src, but may also reload the video.

`document.getElementById("video-player").load()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use videoElement.src = "" instead of videoElement.removeAttribute("src")

Comment: This is a good one!  it does the job without javascript error and it doesn't reload video... Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You could set the background image of the video container element to the poster image.

Then set the video element to opacity 0 when the video ends.

The video essentially hides the image until it's done playing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the `currentTime` to 0?

```
document.getElementById("video-player")[0].currentTime = 0;
```